# Getting an 0x80040153 Error in Unity while implementing with the Hololens

Tags: c#, hololens

I have the following Problem: I am implementing with the Hololens. For orientation I use the Origami tutorial of the Microsoft Academy. Everything was okay. I build my Project and see my result through the Hololens in my room. Today I start Unity and load the same project and get the folowing error now:

> "Unable to retrieve Windows.Graphics.Holographic.HolographicSpace statics: Operation has failed with error 0x80040154: Klasse nicht registriert"

Because of this I am not able to build the project. It always orrcures, when I click with the mouse in the unity window, where you see the GameObjects, or when I want to build the project.

Maybe someone have a solution for this Problem and can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest creator's update, and the latest version of the windows 10 sdk. Also there are multiple versions of the projects files for the tutorials now based on which version of Unity you are using, make there you are using the version that matches your Unity installation.

Comment: I installed now the actual update and the latest version, but the same error orrcures. I found a solution and maybe it helps someone with the same problem ;). When i load a project and the error orrcures I only have to click twice on the play button in unity.